# Boot loop after restart pc

Tags: memory, ssd, motherboard, bios, reboot

Is there anyone who has an idea why my pc is keep restarting? Kinda disturbing when i try to intsall new os on new SSD . And every time i restart the pc either via the reset button or from the Windows, it goes in a boot loop until i pull out the power cable. Then it works fine until the next restart.

I tried to remove video card, changing rams, pull out hdd, but nothing helps.

I have an asrock b85 pro4. P2.0 bios, i5 4460 cpu, 2x 4gb Kingston fury 1600 Mhz.

Comment: What is your Boot order in BIOS?

Comment: Do you think boot order can occure this? I think it's ubs > hdd > uefi , but i am not at home at the moment. I opened boot menu (f11) every time i wanted to boot from usb.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the problem, but i updated the bios through internet flash and ding, i can restart the pc.